# coachable players for RoboCup Soccer Simulator 2d v14

Tags: simulation, robotics, robocup

I am doing a work similar to [this one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4133817) but the coachable players i found [online](http://rcsscoachable.sourceforge.net/) are 3 years old and don't work with the latest version of the [soccer server](http://sserver.sourceforge.net/).

does anyone know any alternatives? or have any sugestions?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a framework for implementing agents that implement the CLang (not the LLVM stuff) language, used by the coach to communicate with the agents using the virtual environment (like it was talking to the players in a soccer field).

The most complete frameworks that I know are Dainamite and agent2d. Take a look at then and see if they implement all the features that you need.

http://www.dainamite.de/

http://pt.sourceforge.jp/projects/rctools/releases/

Good luck!